# onActivityResult doesn't work in API 4.4.4

Tags: android, kotlin, android-4.4-kitkat

My Code works well in API 28 and below except API 19.
the main problem is that **onActivityResult** doesn't call from other activity in my code when i run it in a device with API 19

The *min_sdk* is *17*. *compile_sdk* && *target_sdk* are *27*, so the problem will not solve with changing them.

here is the code from the first Activity:

```
                food.name = name
                intent.putExtra(Food_Name, burgerNameEtxt.text.toString())
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
                finish()
```

and this is where i should receive the result in another Activity:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {

        RequestCode -> {
            when (resultCode) {

                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    var food = getCurrentFood(mMenueItem.id)
                    food.name = data!!.getStringExtra(Food_Name)
                    // doing some thing with data //
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the **RequestCode** is **1** >> **const val RequestCode = 1**
which i send it to the first activity with *intent*. any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you used startActivityForResult?

Comment: yeah >> activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode) @TaseerAhmad

Comment: Are you using any fragments? Could you please generate some logs?

Comment: no, in this case both are _Activity_ . but i do the same thing from a fragment to this activity and it works fine even in API 19  @TaseerAhmad

Comment: That is weird. Have you changed launch modes of your activity?

Comment: there is some part in my project.. when i one do the Task A, i use Fragment and when i need to do Task B i'm using this Activity.. how your question is related to my answer?

Comment: I am still confused about your current code on how it is working. Add more relevant code. If I understood properly, you are starting another activity from your fragment A and when activity is done working, it should give back the result to fragment/activity?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happens because of android:launchMode="singleTask" and this doesn't help intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).

I fixed it by android:launchMode="singleTop".